# Best auto-update component(s) for Delphi

Tags: delphi, components, auto-update

I am re-writing and/or consolidating a bunch of my "app framework" classes (basic mainform, about box, locking routines & purchase linking, auto-update, datamodule initializer, etc) -- Basically, I have a number of small potential shareware apps that I'm wanting to get out the door, and want to re-use code where I can, as well as build a framework for later apps to save time.

In one app I have auto-updating, I'm using LMD's WebUpdate, and am reasonably happy with it, but given that I'm re-vamping everything, I thought I'd see what the consensus is for "best approach" on this.  I don't mind paying for commercial, nor using open source if that's best... just would rather not reinvent the wheel.  (I've read: [Delphi: How do you auto-update your applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277514/delphi-how-do-you-auto-update-your-applications))

What is the best Auto-update component for Delphi Win 32 apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use TWebUpdate from [TMS Components](http://tmssoftware.com) and am very happy with it.  I haven't used LMD so unfortunately am not able to provide a comparison.

TMS also supply a whole raft of other components so if your re-writes require any else, especially if you want some shiny UI enhancements (TMS have a range of iPhone-style components) then the website is certainly worth a visit.

They seem fairly active in their support forums (although I haven't had need to use them for the WebUpdate component) and they have a fairly regular release cycle.

Answer (score 5):

I use [TmxWebUpdate](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=291). It's free, simple and easy to customize. I also own TMS Component Pack with TWebUpdate, but never really found a good incentive to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard good compliment about [TWebUpdate](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/wupdate.asp) from Tmssoftware

also [torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=291) has much components for the same job, some are free and others are commericals.

Now what's the best?, it's depend on your needs, you already using one from LMD, which is a good company and I have very good experince with their components, but never used this one.

If you need a specific functionality, or you have some problems with the current one you are using, it's will be better to list them, so you will get a better answers, but it's hard to define the best, because every one has different experience and views.

Answer (score 1):

I use TWebUpdate myself. It works, but the docs are a bit limited and it seems a bit buggy sometimes.

I have looked into LMD's (I have their full component pack), but it seemed to be much more limited than TWebupdate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using TWebUpdate, and have to echo stg's comments on quality of support (good), and quality of documentation (spotty -- it's old, and doesn't always reflect their new features immediately).

You'll also find some places that stress the "roll your own" approach.

Remember that part of the auto-update issue is the tools that you will need to create the update "package" at your end. TMS Software makes a tool available for use with TWebUpdate, and it's reasonably well done. In my case, I'm "misusing" the component to deal with multiple files so that I can refresh additional related libraries, text files, etc. The update builder tool isn't really good for that. So there's some manual editing. But the updating part works well.

I'll also add a caution that you need to be careful with updates in Vista (and probably Windows 7). Writing to the protected places in the Program Files hierarchy was problematic for me. You may want to check that out with whatever component you use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and "gotcha" warnings esp -- much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Appwave](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/appwave/resources) from Embarcadero. It's not free and I don't know the price.