# How to auto update my program on clients

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, auto-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi: How do you auto-update your applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277514/delphi-how-do-you-auto-update-your-applications)

I want to auto update who using our program.

- Our program is family medicine information system.
- Over 750 doctors using our program.

When I add new files on our servers, all clients must check on server and when find new files download them. if that file exist first kill process, delete file and download it.

until these days we are currently used **AutoUpgrader Pro** on **Code Gear RAD Studio Delphi 2007**. But for now we cant use that system anymore.

As a said how can i auto upgrade?

Thank you for helping.

Note: Our program on **Delphi 2007**.

**Edit** for question **response**: Yes i want to do it myself. look this scenario. 1- I added one of .zip file on my server side. 2- A Doctor, when opening our program, the program shows message to "Update is available, Press OK" after pressing OK on client side 3- Client download .zip file and extract it to application startup location. HOW can i do that with 3rd party programs ? yes

Comment: Do you want to do it yourself, or are you looking for a 3rd party solution? There are about a million different ways to do it, so you really ought to describe some more of your constraints and desiderata.

Comment: Yes i want to do it myself. look this scenario. 1- I added one of .zip file on my server side. 2- A Doctor, when opening our program, the program shows message to "Update is available, Press OK" after pressing OK on client side 3- Client download .zip file and extract it to application startup location. HOW can i do that with 3rd party programs ? yes

Comment: I'll add a suggestion: Offer the download, and prepare it all in the background, but don't stop the doctor getting on with their day. Thus the actual install won't happen until the next day when a swap over is done. This is easiest if the startup app is just a splash, and then runs the main app. Or copies the new one over. And keep backups - your app will be critical.

Comment: Use something like Indy to do the download. Check periodically for updates. When you find one, download it to a temporary location. Whenever the app starts, check if a downloaded update is waiting, and exit the app and install the update if so. That's pretty much it.

Comment: **thank you** for answers, and ken i'll check on that topics.